# pybabel ignoring files with autoescape

Tags: python, localization, internationalization, python-babel

I have a python web application with jinja2 templates. I am using pybabel for localization. When using the `pybabel extract` command, it exports everything exactly as intended, EXCEPT for any files which use the jinja2 `autoescape` tag.

My babel.cfg file has the following line:

```
extensions=jinja2.ext.autoescape,jinja2.ext.with_
```

And the extract command I am using is:

```
pybabel extract -F ./babel.cfg -o ./locale/messages.pot ./
```

I have a file called settings.html, which has the following tag:

```
{% autoescape false %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

And pybabel lists this file in the console, in the list of files it extracts from:

```
extracting messages from templates/cfg/settings.html
```

But, when I check my pot file, there are no translations from settings.html.

If I delete the autoescape tag from settings.html, then re-run the `pybabel extract` command, then it correctly extracts the translations.

So there must be something up with use of autoescape.

Any clues?

Comment: This is an old question but I had a similar problem and it turned out that not all the Jinja2 extensions I used were in my babel.cfg. Did you make sure that they were all included? (except for i18n)

Comment: Yep, they were all included. Actually, it was a typo in the config file.